# Hyperledger Fabric: Gossip Protocol, Where Are Messages Received?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have posted this question on Reddit already, but in hope to receive a few more answers here I go :)

As per title, I am looking for where in the source code of Hyperledger Fabric Gossip Messages are received. What I am trying to achieve is to implement a custom protocol that needs me to modify the underlying source code: when a peer receives a block via Gossip, if the block contains a specific transaction (i.e. Endorser Transaction) then I want this same peer to emit another block (with no endorsement policy connected to it) with a special tag and the node's signature. I already took care of what is needed to create a block with this special tag. Now, I only need to find out where peers received messages, specifically blocks, and check whether the transaction inside is an endorser transaction.

At this scope, I followed where the function [Accept](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/gossip/comm/comm_impl.go#L320) from comm_impl.go is used, and found out it is used when a node starts in order to initialize the "receiving protocol" in [start](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go#L294). In this function, a go [subroutine](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go#L318) is called to accept incoming messages - this points to the function handleMessages. However, in [handleMessages](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go#L331), there is no mention of isDataMsg(), but only of isStateInfoMsg, LeadershipMsg and PullMsg. The only instance of isDataMsg that I have found is within the function [HandleMessage](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/gossip/gossip/channel/channel.go#L601) in gossip/gossip/channel/channel.go. However, adding some print statements, I have seen that it never evaluates to true, only stateInfoMsg and stateInfoPullRequestMsg do.

For this purpose, I now have a few questions:

- What is the purpose of the different stateInfoMsg? How are they different from Pull and DataMsg?
- What is a DataMsg? Why does it never evaluate to true?
- How/Where do other nodes store block messages when they are sent them from the anchor peer?

Essentially, I am trying to understand which piece of code receives block messages. I have been stuck on this for a very long time, and I'd appreciate some help, thank you!

Also, if you need more details about my blockchains structure: I have N nodes/peers, all belonging to N different organizations and only 1 orderer.

PS: I already forked the repository. Also, you can assume that blocks only have 1 transaction.